# Xcode colour theme for Sublime Text 2

Tags: xcode, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Does anyone know if there is a colour scheme I can import into Sublime Text that matches the syntax colours used in Xcode? I've looked high and low and can't find anything. I love sublime but I'm not a fan of the colour schemes and prefer Xcode.

Cheers!

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to make your own...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The excellent [Colorsublime](http://colorsublime.com/) has listed a theme called *XCode Default* that looks like this:

[image: XCode Default theme]

For now it seems to be permalinked [here](http://colorsublime.com/theme/Xcode_default).

Still unsatisfied? Try making your own, as one of the commenters on your question suggested. [TMTheme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/PlasticCodeWrap) can help.

Comment: The direct download link is broken. This is probably the quickest way to find the theme: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acolorsublime.com+xcode

Comment: @finiteloop Thanks. I updated my answer with the theme's apparently new permalink.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all their themes (much easier to navigate) from their github:
https://github.com/Colorsublime/Colorsublime-Themes/tree/master/themes